# Solve out of memory error using Static Program Analysis

Tags: oop, out-of-memory, static-analysis

Out of memory is one of the most frequent errors in java and other OO languages. 
Can we apply static program analysis to reduce "out of memory" errors ? 
I am looking for approaches that aims to reduce this error without running code.
Is there any particular areas of analysis that perform research in this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, static analyzers are able to detect out of bounds. They do it slightly worse than dynamic analyzers, as they cannot trace complex cases of pointer usage. Moreover, static analyzers just cannot obtain some information. Let’s consider an abstract situation:

```
void OutstandingIssue(const char *strCount)
{
  unsigned nCount;
  sscanf_s(strCount, "%u", &nCount);

  int array[10];
  memset(array, 0, nCount * sizeof(int));
}
```

Whether the array index out of bounds happens or not, it will depend on the data 
received from the outside. A static code analyzer is powerless here. Maximum of what it can do here is to warn that the entered value is used without a check. The dynamic analyzer will detect an error during testing the program, while it will receive various variants of input data. These topics are given [here](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0248/) with more details.

But if there is a question “does a static analyzer really help?”, the answer is yes, it does. For example, a collection of bugs gathered by PVS-Studio team contains a good number of this type errors detected by static analyzer: [V512](https://www.viva64.com/en/examples/V512/), [V645](https://www.viva64.com/en/examples/V645/).

Comment: This mainly detects problem related to mem* functions.
What about programming languages like Java ?
Can you do something using static analysis that detects potential out of memory code for java ?

Comment: I don't work with Java and I don't know the exact answer. But I'm sure, that similar errors can be caught in Java using SCA.

Comment: List of tools for static code analysis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java